# Is it considered bad practice to use a raw pointer in a constructor with the intention of wrapping it immediately in a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, raw-pointer

I want users not to have to create smart pointers to pass into object contructors themselves, but instead to pass in a raw pointer and then convert to a smart pointer within the initialisation. However, there are some warning bells ringing regarding creating memory leaks so I wanted to check: Is the following code problematic in any way?

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> num;

public:
    explicit A(int* n){
        num = std::make_unique<int>(*n);
    }
};

int main(){
    int n = 4;
    A a(&n); 
    // A a(std::make_unique<A>(n)); // instead of having to do this, which is a moderately irritating 

};
```

Comment: Since `make_unique()` copies a value, there should be no need for a pointer to be passed at all.   The constructor of `A` can accept an `int`, and then construct a `unique_ptr` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is of course true in this simple example but I think I'm right in saying that this would cause object slicing to base class if `int` were a superclass and the parameter `n` intended to be a subclass.

Comment: In that case, pass the data to the constructor that is needed to construct the contained object (including selecting the right type if needed or, if the object is constructed using a factory idiom, the information needed by the factory).   `make_unique` supports that.

Comment: That strikes me as an odd way to do it.  You may want to read Herb Sutter's guidance about [smart pointer parameters](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid smart pointer in interface, you might use by value or const reference:

```
class A {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> num;

public:
    explicit A(int n) : num(std::make_unique<int>(n)) {}
};
```

Comment: But am I right in saying this method causes problems if `A` was intended to contain a polymorphic class heirachy instead of `int`? For instance, you might need to explicitely declare a subtype as the `make_unique<>` type, therefore preventing our ability to just do `std::make_unique<superclass>`

Comment: You might have something like `template <typename T, typename...Ts> void emplace(Ts&&...);`

Comment: interesting, would you be able to point me to an example, or an additional resource.

Comment: It is mostly duplicate `make_unique` signature, but as member.